# How to use SCSS variables into my React components

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I am working on a React project that follows this structure

```
src |
  components |
    Footer |
      index.jsx
      styles.scss
    Header |
      index.jsx
      styles.scss
    scss |
      helpers.scss
      variables.scss
      ...
    main.scss
```

Into my variables file I was using the `css` custom variables so, all them where on `:root` and I can access them in my components styles.

When I wanted to create the dark colours I wanted to use the SCSS function `darken`, but it does not evaluate them and throws an error saying that `var(--blue)` is not a valid colour.

As a solution I decided to move all the variables into a SCSS variables but when project is building it throws another error that says that a `$blue` is not defined.

The unique solution possible I can use, it is to include the variables file in all the styles files but, I do not know if there are a better solution for the structure that I am using.

Comment: I know this question is 3 years old, but anyone looking for an up-to-date solution might find [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119188/how-to-get-scss-variables-into-react/66120027#66120027) helpful as it addresses the necessairy options for css-loader.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]If you don't want to use `styled-component`
then you can follow this link.
https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript

Comment: the file shall be called variables.module.scss

Answer (score 30):

**From React 17**

To access your scss variables into the react component, you need to do something like that

1. Install `node-sass` as a dependency or dev dependency
2. No need to do any config change in webpack
3. import as a module <-- main point

**variables.module.scss**

```
$color: skyblue;
$primaryColor: red;

:export {
    color: $color;
    primary-color: $primaryColor;
}
```

**App.js**

```
import variables from '<YOUR_PATH>/variables.module.scss';

const App = () => {
    console.log(variables);
}
```

Comment: This is not tied to React 17 and will work in any React version.

Answer (score 6):

I use a similar structure to organize my .scss files. I like having the styles in the same folder as the component. However, I import all scss files to my `main.scss` file. This helps avoid style conflicts in the DOM.

main.scss

```
import "./scss/helpers.scss"
import "./variables.scss"
import "./Footer/style.scss"
import "./Header/styles.scss"
```

Make sure to name your files with an underscore so that all the files get merged on compilation. Note you don't need to name the underscore in the import.

```
_helpers.scss
_variable.scss
_style.scss
```

Using this method you only need to import styles once into your app.  `index.jsx`

Comment: Doing this allows using code splitting? What happens if you have a very big project?

Comment: I do this with very large projects. I like having small scss files right next to their components. As far as performance. What I have found with other systems is often there are DOM conflicts where one css style overrides the other. Using partials there is no styles overwritten in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways I can recomend you to tackle this.

1- Duplicate the values of those variables. Add them both on your variables.scss and as constants in some other file, maybe config.js or constants.js that way you'll be able to reference these values from your react components, the downside to this, is you'll have to remember to change them in two places if you have to modify the value.

2- Consider using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/). With styled components you can define your styles within your components, using variables or props within the styles.

3- Use some mechanism to define these variables in a single file or as environment variables, and setup your build process to be able to import these values into js and scss files.

Comment: I will look into the styled components.

Comment: first alternative is bad advice!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use custom variables with that project structure using [css-vars](https://github.com/malyw/css-vars) mixin.

After proposing the option to evaluate custom variables before executing the SCSS function, a guy suggested me this mixin. I have just tested and works pretty nice.